# Import ResultEvent in Flash

Tags: apache-flex, flash, actionscript-3

I would like to import the Flex class ResultEvent in Flash.

This is how I did it:

1. In "Publish Settings/Flash/ActionScript 3.0 Settings/Library Path" I selected the rpc.swf (from the flex sdk)
2. Then I wrote in my flash-file: import mx.rpc.ResultEvent;

But I still get the following error:

> 1046: Type was not found or was not a
>   compile-time constant: ResultEvent.

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Thanks, Vincent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ResultEvent class is part of mx.rpc.events

```
import mx.rpc.events.ResultEvent;
```

Comment: Ok, indead. Stupid mistake by me.
Thanks a lot.